# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre (String) y .toString()?

Tags: java

Estoy utilizando JAVA para programar una replica de un programa que tengo en VB.NET. Estaba creando los "DataGrids" (usando JTable´s) y programando para que aparezcan Tooltips sobre las celdas de mi JTable... sep, en JAVA hay que hacerlo todo desde 0.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ok, mi curiosidad comienza cuando al escribir las siguientes lineas de codigo se cuelga un error en el programa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 DataGridMed = new JTable(){
        @Override
        public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int col){
            Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, col);
            if(c instanceof Component){
                JComponent jc = (JComponent) c;
                jc.setToolTipText((String) getValueAt(row,col)); <--- ERROR
            }
            return c;
        }
    };
```

Me quede un poco indignado, ya que cuando hago un casting de esa forma, ¿no estoy yo convirtiendo ese valor en un objeto String?, al cambiar esa linea por .toString(), error desaparece por completo...!

```
jc.setToolTipText(getValueAt(row,col).toString);
```

Se claramente que "String" se trata de una clase, y que no pertenece al grupo de tipos primitivos de datos (int, boolean, float, double . . . ). Es por eso que al momento de comparar dos cadenas String, el operador "==" no sirve y necesitas usar ".Equals()"... Pero en este caso no estoy distinguiendo cual es la diferencia de hacer un casting y usar .toString().

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Exactamente que ocurrio aqui?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si te vas a la documentación de `Java` para el apartado de **[`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)** puedes observar que el método `getValueAt` devuelve un `Objeto`:

```
public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
    return rowData[row][col];
}
```

por lo tanto al intentar hacer el casteo está intentando generar el `String` directamente del objeto y, si este no extiende de `String`, no se va a poder producir dicho casteo.

Sin embargo, el método `toString` llama al método `toString` que se encuentra en todos los datos que heredan de `Object`, y este método si que hace una representación del Objeto en manera de `String`.

Por lo tanto, con el primer método te da error si el casteo no puede ser correcto. Sin embargo, con el segundo no te va a dar error ya que el tipo de dato que introduces es un `String` que es lo que necesita el método `setToolTipText`.

Answer (score 3):

Primero, lo fácil. `toString()` es simplemente un método que devuelve una representación del objeto como `String`. Como es parte de la definición de `Object`, todas las clases tienen ese método (aunque la implementación básica no sea de mucha ayuda). Es decir, para cualquier objeto, puedes hacer `objeto.toString()` y obtener un `String`.

`(String)` hace un cast a String. Cuando tienes una referencia a un objeto, al hacer una asignación a una variable de una subclase, tienes que especificar el `cast`. **La clase del objeto no cambia**, si intentas hacer un `cast` a `String` de un objeto que no es un `String`, entonces en tiempo de ejecución lanza una excepción(`ClassCastException`). Funciona así

```
String str1 = new String("Hola");
Object obj1 = str1;
String str2 = (String) obj1; // Asignas una referencia de superclase (Object) a subclase (String), cast es necesario.

Integer int1 = new Integer(1);
String str3 = (String) int1; // Error de compilación, Integer no es superclase de String

Integer int2 = new Integer(2);
Object obj2 = int2;
String str4 = (String) obj2; // No hay error de compilación porque pasa de referencia de Object a referencia de String,
                             // pero lanza ClassCastException en tiempo de ejecución porque
                             // la instancia que se asigna a str4 es un Integer y no un String.
```

Answer (score 1):

Como ya lo dijeron:

`.toString()`  <-- es un método que muestra la representación textual de un objeto

`String` <-- es un Objeto (Tipo de dato de cadena de caracteres)

Al usar  `(String)objeto` lo que se intenta es convertir dicho objeto a `String` directamente y puede haber errores de conversión, al utilizar `.toString()` <-- Simpre va a convertir el objeto a un `String`, aunque algunas veces no regrese el valor esperado.