# Error recuperando un String tras almacenarlo como Object

Tags: java

Tengo esta parte de código:

```
System.out.print("nombre: ");
String nombre = leer.nextLine();

while(!nombre.equals("fin")){
    mc.insertar(mc, 0);
    System.out.print("nombre: ");
    nombre = leer.nextLine();
}
for (int i = 0; i < mc.cantidad();i++) {
    String aux = (String) mc.obtener(i);
    System.out.println(aux + " - "+aux.length()+" caracteres");
}
```

Al momento de llegar a esta parte (gracias al debug): `String aux = (String) mc.obtener(i);`

Manda el siguiente mensaje de error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   Colecciones.CColeccion cannot be cast to java.lang.String     at
>   Colecciones.CTest.main(CTest.java:27)

En la clase `CColeccion` el método `obtener()` está así:

```
public Object obtener(int i){
    return datos[i];
}
```

El tipo de dato con el cual estoy trabajando es este: `private Object datos[] = null;` (práctica antes de pasar a `ArrayList`, genéricas y dinámicas).

***¿Cómo lo convierto a String para que me dé el nombre?***

Comment: El error es claro , el objeto es de clase `CColeccion` por eso debe hacer el `cast` a este tipo primero `((CColeccion)mc.obtener(i)).getAtributo()`  y luego acceder a algún atributo. sería bueno que añadiera el método `insertar` y que tipo de variable es `mc`

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre (String) y .toString()?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/38569/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-string-y-tostring)

Comment: No @SJuan76, no se le parece en nada. Por favor, retira la petición de cierre por duplicado.

Comment: He editado el título de tu pregunta para evitar que la cierre o por duplicado o porque no está claro lo que preguntas. Espero que tengas un momento para echar un vistazo a las respuestas y les dejes un comentario a cada una con tu opinión.

Answer (score 2):

Tu error se encuentra en esta línea de código:

```
mc.insertar(mc, 0);
```

En ella estás insertando en tu instancia de `CColeccion` (llamada `mc`) una referencia a ella misma (`mc`) en vez de insertar la cadena obtenida en el paso anterior.

El error que estás recibiendo, que es una excepción en tiempo de ejecución y no un error de compilación, se debe a que estás tratando de recuperar un `String` a partir de una referencia a `CColeccion`, de ahí la excepción "CColeccion cannot be cast to String" ("Una CColeccion no puede ser convertida a String").

Cambiando el programa para que guarde el contenido de `nombre`, un `String`, el código queda:

```java
System.out.print("nombre: ");
String nombre = leer.nextLine();

while(!nombre.equals("fin")){
    mc.insertar(nombre, 0);
    System.out.print("nombre: ");
    nombre = leer.nextLine();
}

for (int i = 0; i < mc.cantidad();i++) {
    String aux = (String) mc.obtener(i);
    System.out.println(aux + " - "+aux.length()+" caracteres");

}
```

Ahora la recuperación del `String` almacenado se realizará de manera satisfactoria y sin lanzar la excepción en tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: Que burda era este error, pero lo resolviste siguiendo los pasos de la página, así que no tengo más que aceptarla.

Comment: Este tipo de error suele pasarnos a todos, y no solemos solucionarlo hasta que otras personas, desde un punto de vista diferente, se dan cuenta de ellos (o tras darse un buen descanso para refrescar la mente).